# How to add extra filters to a searchresults page in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, filter, forms

In my Codeigniter website I've made a searchform. When I search the page is redirected to a 'searchresults' page.

I always get a lot results and I want to minimize that. I would like to add searchfilters to the 'searchresults' page, so I can search on specific categories/keywords.

I've been searching for this the whole day.

What I've tried is adding a dropdown and a input field to the searchresults page. The dropdown is populated with the categories found with the normal searchform. This works, but I can't filter and limit the searchresutls when I submit the 'second searchform'.

My form on the 'searchresults' page looks like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

            $(".zoekfilters").hide();
            $(".filters").show();

        $('.filters').click(function(){
        $(".zoekfilters").slideToggle();
        });

    });

    </script>

<div class="zoekfilters">
<br/>
    <form action="home/get_filtered_vac" method="post">
    <p class="field">
    <label class="field">Categorie:</label>
        <select name="catselect" id="selection" value="Categorie">
            <option selected disabled value="">Selecteer een categorie</option>
        <?php foreach($all as $dat  ){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $dat['categorie']; ?>"><?php echo $dat['categorie']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </p>
    <br/>
    <p class="field">
    <label class="field">Tags:</label>
        <input name="tag" type="search" placeholder="Tags">
    </p>
    <br/>
    <p class="field">
    <label class="field">Aantal uren:</label>
    <?php foreach($all as $dat){ ?>
    <?php echo $dat['uren']; nbs(2); ?>
    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $dat['uren']; ?>">
    <?php } ?>
    </p>
    <br/>
    <p class="field">
        <input type="submit" value="Filter resultaten">
    </p>    
    </form>
```

---

You can try it yourself, so the idea is clear:

1. Go to: http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/vacatures
2. leave the big searchbox empty and add '9101' to the small searchbox, Now wait a second an then submit the form. You will be redirected to http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/vacatureresults
3. Click on 'Zoekfilters' to open the second searchfrom on the 'searchresults' page.

If people need my model functions I will post them.

Comment: again same question what is the reason not to use the datatables http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: Why using DataTables? Which page with searchengines uses DataTables? I don't want to show my data inside a table..

Comment: Maybe I could just use a jquery plugin to hide records that aren't relevant to my filter options?

Comment: Database error in your provided link

Comment: Yes, the searchfunction is still a bit buggy. You ahve to wait a second or so before submitting the form. I just tried a jquery filter plugin that just hides the fields that aren't relevant. that would work too. but I don't know if there's a better way.